# .stop() isn't working with my hover, to make quick movement work - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble with a hover. If you quickly move your mouse in and out of an area it fires the .show() but not the .hide(). I'm not sure if it works in other browsers but it's not in Chrome.

You can see a sample at the link below. I've tried the all the true false variations with .stop() but it's not working. I appreciate your help and I'm sure I'm just doing something silly.

http://jsfiddle.net/glenn2223/xBgVe/2/

```
.stop().show('slide', {direction: 'up'}, "fast", false);
```

Many thanks for your help,
      glenn2223

Comment: working fine on `chrome  35.0.1916.153 m` and `firefox 31.0`

Comment: Do a hard refresh (ctrl + f5) and see if it's working.

Comment: It easy to recreate the bug, just have to mouse over quick and the event does not fire.

Comment: Nope, hard refresh still gives no joy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why, but while `show()` and `hide()` don't work, `slideToggle` does. This seems to solve your problem (although I had to remove `height: auto !important` from your css because it was overriding jQuery's height).

http://jsfiddle.net/prankol57/YBsYh/

Javascript:

```
jQuery(function () {
    $("ol.top-nav li").hover(function () {
        $(this).children('div.subl').stop().slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

I believe this is because `show()` and `hide()` do not cause an animation queue.

Comment: That solves my problem. Thanks a bunch. I saw what you meant by the height auto css, messes up the slide doesn't it. This reduces my code as well, always a bonus. A MASSIVE TICK!! for you